# Chrome not loading view from ajax after submiting forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to get view of the page from ajax and put in some div. I am currently working in Codeigniter.

### Jquery Ajax

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("form#data").submit(function(){
       // form validation rules..
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "index.php/hotels/quick_addNewHotel",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#form-alert").html(" ");
                $("#step1").removeClass("progtrckr-todo").addClass("progtrckr-done");
                $("#quick_setup").html(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
     }); 

  });
```

### Controller (hotels)

```
 function quick_addNewHotel()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
         //php code to post input form data to database

         $this->load->view('quickSetup/addNewHotel');
    } 
}
```

Above code is working fine in Firefox. View are loaded to div on ajax success. But when tried in Chrome.

Forms data are submitted successfully and stored in database. But instead to loading view `$this->load->view('quickSetup/addNewHotel')`, it is redirected to previous page, which is page that contains forms been submitted. Does my code has any error.

Comment: You should be using `$this->load->view('quickSetup/addNewHotel',$data,TRUE);` to get the data instead of rendering view in ajax.

Comment: I need to render all views that page contains. Not only data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `e.preventDefault();` before `var formData` and you'll be fine. Also change `function()` to `function(e)`. I think `return false;` is not enough for Chrome.

Hope I helped. :)

Comment: It worked after i added e.preventDefault. But its not working with non-formData. Any solution

Comment: If it's working, please accept my answer, because it's an answer to your specific question. Thank you. Also if you explain this non-formData context for me, I'll help if I can.

Comment: Your code worked for me in first case. I am submiting form and again another form display and when I try to submit another form then pages refresh in chrome. In firefox it works well. Any solution

Comment: Is ```e.preventDefault();``` there? Are you submitting the same form again? Btw I don't understand why don't just create a simple button, register a click handler on it and send the form data when user clicks on that button. You don't need a submit button for this.

Comment: So there was not any problem. I wonder it worked when i wrote my scripts at top then html. first it was html then script. Its strength how these can be error.